What does "(be) able to look sad" mean?
I found the following sentence on the Collins online dictionary:

She was somehow able to look sad and cheerful at the same time.

For my understanding, when I say "she looks sad," it means I think that observers of her feel she is sad.
Now when I say "she is able to look sad," does it mean I have some thought, which is not so much firm as when I say "she looks sad", that the observers feel she is sad? Do I totally misunderstand the sentence?

The full sentence is "She was somehow able to look sad and cheerful at the same time." Now where is the problem?

The subject of the sentence is "she", and there is nobody else referred to. The sentence is saying that she can carry two contrasting emotions at the same time.

She looks sad means that she has the appearance of a sad person to any observer, not just 'me'.  If you want to say that your opinion is different from someone else's, you can add to me. "You think she looks happy? She looks sad to me."

I edited based on Kate-san's comment. Thank you.

Look means both "to have an appearance that befits or accords with" and "to express by the eyes or facial expression", so it can refer to something passive or active. I'm not sure I understand the question though.

Sometimes words work together as a phrase to have a unique meaning. Here, "able to look sad" isn't really a phrase on it's own; the important phrase is "able to (verb)." This sentence works the same as "she was able to ride a unicycle." Sad and cheerful might seem contradictory, so the sentence notes it as a surprising "ability." Without more context, we don't know whether she actually has mixed emotions, or is simply giving a mixed outward appearance.

@AndyBonner It's (be able)(verb). Be able works much like a modal verb, but can be tensed - was able, will be able, etc.

You are adding layers that aren't there: "I have some thought, which is not so much firm ... that the observers feel she is sad." It's more fact than opinion, a firm statement, about her and not observers.

If you say ”She looks sad,” then you are looking at her, and her expression or demeanor is one you associate with sadness. If you say ”She is able to look sad,” you are commenting on her ability to effect an expression or demeanor associated with sadness.

You can swap out the word look and use others such as seem, or appear, or present the semblance of (sadness and cheerfulness), or simply be.

You mention observers. There's only one observer who counts: the person making the comment. There's an implicit assumption that anyone looking at her would read the same internal emotional state. (This is largely true; humans are an extremely social species, with a sizeable portion of our brains hard-wired to help us recognize and empathize with the internal mental & emotional states of other humans.)


Now when I say "she is able to look sad," does it mean I have some thought, which is not so much firm as when I say "she looks sad", that the observers feel she is sad? Do I totally misunderstand the sentence?

If I understand correctly, you are asking whether "she is able to look sad" suggests more uncertainty as to whether people will believe she is sad from looking at her than "she looks sad"?
If so the answer is "no", I don't think that sentence is suggesting that at all and I don't think it's what that phrase would be understood as in general. "She is able to look sad" just means "she has the capacity to look sad". Like, the opposite of a situation of someone who never looked sad even if they were sad or wanted to look sad.
It's not an idiomatic phrase with a strange meaning, it's a normal sentence we understand from understanding the words in it. It means what it looks like what it means, basically.
I'm also guessing you're parsing the sentence wrong. You're focusing on "able to look sad" when actually the sentence is parsed like this:

She was somehow able to [look [[sad and cheerful] [at the same time]]].

In other words the sentence isn't talking about her ability to look sad (something that's not particularly unusual or notable), but a more unusual ability to look sad and cheerful simultaneously.

Thank you very much for correcting my misunderstanding as well as clarifying what I wanted to address here.  Your explanation and Machavity-san's example enlightened me.

There are some expressions that convey multiple (sometimes seemingly contradictory) emotions. What this usually means is that one of the emotions is purely a facade. The real emotion is "leaking through" the facade just enough that an observant person (or narrator) can see through it.
A good example here would be the parent of a child who is slowly dying. The parent is clearly sad over the impending death of their child, but they don't want to show that sadness to their child. Thus, the parent smiles a lot and maybe acts as if they are happy or nothing is wrong. That might fool the child, but an outside observer will note that the parent is not, in fact, happy or cheerful, etc. In other words, they look happy, but the happiness is an act and their real emotion is sadness.

Thank you very much for the example that is very helpful for understanding the sentence. My first read actually led me to imaging she was an actress or something, which seemed strange to me since dictionary editors would not had been likely to choose the sentence in that sense.   I am cursing myself for my poor imagination...hahaha

I think a description of this would be "looks happy while she is actually sad", not looking sad and happy at the same time.

The past tense phrase "was able to do X" can mean either of two things, and may or may not imply that the person actually did X. Consider the following examples:

My father was able to fix any appliance he could get his hands on.
My father was able to fix the leaky sink that had been bothering me all week.

In sentence 1, "was able to" means "had the capacity to", while in sentence 2 it means something closer to "managed to." The latter sentence indicates that the father actually did fix the sink, not just that he was capable of doing so. The sentence "she's able to look sad" on its own reads to me as meaning she has the capacity to be sad, but it could go either way with the right context:

She struggles to display most emotions, but she's able to look sad. (Describing general qualities = has the capacity to look sad)
Although she's at a party surrounded by her friends, she's able to look sad. (Describing a specific situation = manages to look sad in this moment)


Thank you Carmeister-san for showing me the variety of the "able" usages.
